# How to Mass Decryption of Computer on Network

Tags: vbscript

I would like to be able to do a mass decryption of computers on my network for a project. I currently make use of the following method on each computer (have to touch each computer manually):

Login remotely to computer: **PSEXEC \hostname cmd.exe**
Once remote login has been done i run the following command: **Manage -bde -off c:**

I tried to do the following: **For /f %i in hostname.txt do psexec \%i manage -bde -off c:**
The problem with above is that the computer needs to be online and on the network at the time of running the script.

What I need is to somehow run this script in a loop and basically mark each computer in the hostname.txt file with a "1" as been done and then move onto the next computer, if it can't find the previous computer online, until all computer are finished or marked as "1".

Your assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: With **PSEXEC** you can specify a text file for list of computers to push the command. Also why do you need to login remotely then "Manage -bde -off c:"? You can just throw this command into PSEXEC. Using a batch file will be hard to do logging and retrying. I would use VBS, as you can do logging with Excel.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for the feedback, is it possible to provide such a VBA script in excel to me as I do not have VBA knowladge

Comment: There are many things to consider before starting some code that depend on your environment. You use VBS to create excel log, and push the command to remote workstations. Is this **Manage** a .exe file on all your remote systems in folder system32? You can even have the VBS to lookup AD for list of computers. Also how do you know if **Manage** completes successfully? Does it create a log?